# How to retrieve particular user data from MySQL database and display in listview?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing Android app that is canteen automation system. I wanted to display the all order which are placed by user and that I have stored in order table. Now problem is that I have no idea how to retrieve data from MySQL and display in list view for that particular user order history data.

This is for my final year project.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class OrderScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextId;
    private Button buttonGet;
    private TextView textViewResult;
    private ProgressDialog loading;
    String result = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_screen);
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("login", 0);
        String user_id = sp.getString("userid", null);
        editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
        editTextId.setText(user_id);
        buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);


        buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    List<Map<String, String>> countryList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    private void getData() {
        String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
        if (id.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Fetching...", false, false);

        String url = Config.DATA_URL + editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(OrderScreen.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSON(String response) {
        String name = "";


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

            for(int i=0; i<result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String[] values = new String[]{collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME)};

                // address = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
                //   vc = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);


                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }



        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using any backend technology to get the data from MySQL database to your android app? With that said, are you using any web APIs to get the data from server i.e. MySQL database?

Comment: I need a brief explanation about the db and Api calls. Here I included the Sample links for your Reference 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413326/android-to-wamp-server-connection-using-android-studio-and-php   2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001667/android-studio-application-connection-with-mysql

Comment: hi satish , i m using php json ... i am sorry i can not explain much because i am very new to this android programming

Comment: thank you siva... i saw your reference link.. i have already done the connection with my sql .. nw i have to retrieve particular user order data in his order history table ...but i don't know how i can do that

Comment: (Aside, to contact people here, please use their @ handle e.g. `@SatishSaini` or `@siva`, otherwise they may not see your message).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to write a backend API in PHP. Consider the following:

- The Android app will need to send HTTP messages to that system to read or write data.
- Every message from the app must contain credentials to prove that the app is authorised to read or write the data.
- If security is important to you, the API should be run over HTTPS, so that credentials are more difficult for third parties to intercept.
- It is common for APIs to use JSON for data input and output, but XML is fine too.
- If you want to read the orders placed by the user, then you might use this format:

  ```
  GET /orders?user=<user>&password=<password>
  ```

  If you place the credentials in the query string like this, it is important to use HTTPS, though I suppose for a study project it does not matter to much.
- Your API should then run a piece of SQL against the database to read the orders, something like:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM order
  INNER JOIN food_item_order ON (order.id = food_item_order.order_id)
  INNER JOIN food_item ON (food_item_order.food_item_id = food_item.id)
  WHERE order.user_id = ?
  ```

  I've implied a four table database here, with the three items above forming a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Hello,, can you please provide the sample code for this above solution

Comment: @Urvashi: no, that's not how this community works. You're not wanting a "sample code", you want me to do the whole thing for you. It's not fair to expect people to do that amount of work for you, but moreover since this is for an academic project, it needs to be predominantly your own work.

Comment: The purpose of my breaking it down was to **suggest an order of tasks for you**. I wish I had such a source of help when I was doing my undergraduate degree ~20 years ago! To get started, write a small PHP program that outputs a fixed piece of JSON, like so: `<?php echo json_encode(["weather" => "sunny", ]);`. Then consume it in your Android app by searching on how to do it. You can then build from there.

Comment: now i have got the data from order table in my list view but now thing is that its retrieving last order data that i have placed but i want entire order data in list view

Comment: ^ Code won't format nicely in comments @Urvashi - if you want to show code then please add it into your question, using the [edit feature](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43698361/edit). The question is presently too broad anyway, so if you can make it more about where you are presently stuck, that will be very helpful for readers. Thanks.

Comment: Please do needful

Comment: Thanks for the question edit @Urvashi. Don't forget to edit it to explicitly state what you are stuck on - presently the question is too broad and there's a code dump at the end of it. Explain to readers what the code does (or is meant to do) and what you are stuck on.